# Explanation to PDE $u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0$ solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, alternative-proof, cauchy-problem

> Exercise: Solve the Cauchy problem $u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0$ with conditions $u(x,0)=g(x)$ and $u_t(x,0)=h(x)$, where $g(x)=0,\ h(x)=\begin{cases} 0,\ x<0  \\ 1,\ x\ge0
> \end{cases}$.

**Please ignore this 'solution' and see Felix Marin's solution**

Solution:

By D'Alembert formula I get

$$u(x,t)=\dfrac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}0 \,\mathrm{d}s=0,\quad x<0.$$
and
$$u(x,t)=\dfrac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}1 \,\mathrm{d}s=t.\quad x\ge0.$$

Thus  the answer is $0,\ if\ x<0\ and\ t,\ if\ x\ge 0$.

---

$\color{fuchsia}{Questions\ about\ the\ answer\ given\ by\ Marin.} $

1. Why the integral of $F'(x)=-\dfrac{1}{2}h(x)$ is $F(x)-F(a)|_{a<0} $ ? Why $a<0$?
2. Why $$\frac{-1}{2}\int_{a}^xh(ε) \,\mathrm{d}ε =\frac{-1}{2}H(x) \int_{0}^xh(ε) \,\mathrm{d}ε?$$

According to Wikipedia, $H(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x δ(ε) \,\mathrm{d}ε$.

Please help me to understand the solution of this Cauchy problem.

---

If there is an alternative solution, maybe an easier one, please show it :)

Comment: I upvoted your question for the efforts you have shown

Comment: :) thanks @Isham I'm new in this topics so..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$By d'Alembert's formula,$$
u(x, t) = \frac{1}{2c} \int_{x - ct}^{x + ct} h(s) \,\d s.
$$

For $x \leqslant -ct$,$$
u(x, t) = \frac{1}{2c} \int_{x - ct}^{x + ct} h(s) \,\d s = \frac{1}{2c} \int_{x - ct}^{x + ct} 0 \,\d s = 0.
$$
For $-ct < x \leqslant ct$,$$
u(x, t) = \frac{1}{2c} \int_{x - ct}^{x + ct} h(s) \,\d s = \frac{1}{2c} \int_0^{x + ct} 1 \,\d s = \frac{1}{2c} (x + ct).
$$
For $x > ct$,$$
u(x, t) = \frac{1}{2c} \int_{x - ct}^{x + ct} h(s) \,\d s = \frac{1}{2c} \int_{x - ct}^{x + ct} 1 \,\d s = t.
$$
Thus$$
u(x, t) = \begin{cases}
0; & x \leqslant -ct\\
\dfrac{1}{2c} (x + ct); & -ct < x \leqslant ct\\
t; & x > ct
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help Alex!

Comment: Why for $-ct<x\le ct,\ \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}=\int_0^{x+ct}$ ?

Comment: Yes, I see it now. When you are going to use d'Alembert formula, Is it a rule of thumb to always analyse the cases for $x$  like this:  $x\le ct,-ct<x\le ct$ and $x<ct$?

Comment: @Isa It depends on the discontinuous points of boundary conditions. In this case, $h$ is discontinuous at $x=0$, so it's necessary to separate the cases in which $x+ct>0$ or not and $x-ct>0$ or not.

Comment: hmm how do you get the inequalities then $(x\le -ct)$ if you are only considering strict inequalities $x+ct>0$ or not and $x-ct>0$ or not ?

Comment: @Isa Because $h$ is Lebesgue-integrable, the end ponits doesn't affect integration. If $h$ is instead some generalized function like the δ function, then d'Alembert's formula may fail.

Comment: ok, I think I get it.

Comment: Would you mind to take a look at this question (answered by me) of a similar pde problem ? Is it correct? I solved it using your method. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709268/about-the-solution-of-wave-equation

Comment: @Isa Yes, it's correct.

Comment: With $\left(a > 0\right)$, $-\,{1 \over 2}\int_{a}^{x}\mathrm{h}\left(\xi\right)\,\mathrm{d}\xi =
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\mathrm{H}\left(-x\right)\left(-a\right) - {1 \over 2}\,\mathrm{H}\left(x\right)\left(x - a\right) = {a \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\,\mathrm{H}\left(x\right)\left(-a\right) - {1 \over 2}\,\mathrm{H}\left(x\right)\left(x - a\right) = {a \over 2} - {1 \over 2}\,\mathrm{H}\left(x\right)x$.

Any left constant disappears when we evaluate $\mathrm{F} - \mathrm{G}$. So, I chose the case $a < 0$ in my answer because it was the simplest one (It doesn't matter).

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Lets start from the very beginning. Lets
>   $\ds{\mrm{u}\pars{x,t} = \mrm{F}\pars{x - t} + \mrm{G}\pars{x + t}}$ with the scaling $\ds{ct \mapsto t}$.

$$
0 = \mrm{u}\pars{x,0} = \mrm{F}\pars{x} + \mrm{G}\pars{x} \implies \mrm{G}\pars{x} = -\,\mrm{F}\pars{x}
$$
The solution becomes
$\ds{\mrm{u}\pars{x,t} = \mrm{F}\pars{x - t} - \mrm{F}\pars{x + t}}$ and

\begin{align}
&\mrm{h}\pars{x} = \mrm{u}_{t}\pars{x,0} = -\mrm{F}'\pars{x} - \mrm{F}'\pars{x} \implies \mrm{F}'\pars{x} = -\,{1 \over 2}\mrm{h}\pars{x}
\\[5mm] &\
\mrm{F}\pars{x} -
\left.\vphantom{\Large A}\mrm{F}\pars{a}\right\vert_{\ a\ <\ 0}= -\,{1 \over 2}\int_{a}^{x}\mrm{h}\pars{\xi}\,\dd\xi =
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\mrm{H}\pars{x}\int_{0}^{x}\mrm{h}\pars{\xi}\dd\xi =
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\mrm{H}\pars{x}x
\end{align}

> where $\ds{\mrm{H}}$ is the *Heaviside Step Function*.

---

$$
\bbx{\mrm{u}\pars{x,t} =
{\mrm{H}\pars{x + t}\pars{x + t} - \mrm{H}\pars{x - t}\pars{x - t}\over 2}}
$$

[image]

Comment: @Isham I think Felix is using $h$ to denote the heaviside function $h(\cdot) = 1, x \ge 0$ and $0$ otherwise. Not to be confused with the initial condition $h$. Maybe the solution would be better written as $$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2} \bigg[ H(x+t)(x+t) - H(x-t)(x-t) \bigg]$$

Comment: Oh thanks @Mattos

Comment: Why the therm $h(x)$ appears when you change the lower limit of integral ?

Comment: @Mattos $0$ k. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixMarin its better now less confusing Thanks +1

Comment: @Isa If $x < 0$ the integral vanishes out. So, we are left with the case $x > 0$. The function, as a prefactor, takes care of this situation. By the way, I already change $\mathrm{h}$ by $\mathrm{H}$ (the $Heaviside\ Step\ Function$) as suggested by $\texttt{@Mattos}$.

Comment: why to find $F(x)$ you integrate from $-\infty$ to $x$? why to choose these limits ?

Comment: @Isa It's irrelevant. But any negative value is convenient. With a positive limit you get the same result but you have to divide the problem in particular cases according to the $x$ sign. We prefer the 'easy' way.

Comment: the idea is to integrate respect to $dx$ so $x$ varies in the integral, should not be $\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x)dx$ then ?

Comment: @Isa The idea is to get $\mathrm{F}\left(x\right)$ because we need it to find the general solution.

Comment: yes I know, I just can't understand the limits of the integral